# can not display new product in new server after migration

Tags: magento, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, magento-1.4

i'm really stuck with this problem, i've inserted manually new product in my magento, it's done saved to database, i've configure all the product:

```
make it enabled, in stock, quantity more than 0, etc..
flush the magento cache..
make the folder permission 777..
```

then i reload my magento, the product still dissapear, eventhought the total are 31 but only 30 product that showing. i've trying to change the user and group just like the old server, but still the same. And then because my new product not display, my footer also (at current page) not also displaying. i check /media/catalog/product/cache/ folder is not modified after i inserted new product.

i've almost searched all the possibility solution but fail. it's been almost a week for only 1 problem.

here the link: http://angzdna.org/mag_16/brands/tulusdoor/flush.html?limit=60

[image: screenshot]

i really need help guys..

Comment: I can see 31 products ..?What is the problem..?Is it fixed ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is fixed, after headache for days. it's not the magento, my new server extension for magento is not complete installed. i missed *gd* and *mcrypt* extension..
thank's for all the respond..

Answer (score 0):

I have face this problem before. Please try to remove .htaccess in sub folder. (not in your public_html)

Hope this can help.

Comment: i did it before inside media folder, not worked..